# r - calculate frequency of one category based on selected variable

Tags: r, frequency, percentage

I have a data frame called **stats** with two columns **Gender** and **Transportation.used** as shown below:

```
Gender    Transportation.used
Male      Bus
Male      Car
Female    Car
Male      Car
Male      Motorcycle
Female    Bus
```

and the list go on.. (or view here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GROIi.jpg)

```
data_stats <- read.table(text="Gender   Transportation.used
Male    Bus
Male    Car
Female  Car
Male    Car
Male    Motorcycle
Female  Bus
Female  Bus
Female  Bus
Female  Bus
Male    Car
Female  Car
",header=T)
```

What I wanna do is to calculate the frequency for gender based on the **selected transport**. I will need the data later on to plot a percentage bar graph. Desired output as below:

```
          Male    Female
   Bus    1        4
```

So how do I calculate in order to get the data? I'm still a beginner in using R, please do help me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try, for frequencies,

```
table(stats)
```

or, for relative frequencies,

```
prop.table(table(stats))
```

or, even better (e.g.),

```
 xtabs(male ~ car, data = stats)
```

I add few examples:

```
dt  <- data.frame(gender = rep(c("Male", "Female"), c(4, 2) ), trans = rep(c("Car", "Bus", "Bike"), c(3, 2, 1) ))

table(dt)
        trans
gender   Bike Bus Car
Female    1   1   0
Male      0   1   3
```

In any case, with the data I have composed from your question, we are working with factors. If you want more options with tables you should operate few class conversions.

**EDIT:**

Here the answer to the problem you posted in the comments. By adjusting the arguments of `dt$colname`, you can get a finer control over the final output.

```
table(dt$gender[dt$trans=="Car"])

Female   Male 
     0      3
```

Comment: I'm sorry I already fixed my question. What I mean is how do I calculate the frequency for gender based on **only one selected transport** in a table? I was able to find the frequency table for all the transports but not the selected one.

Comment: @Annie `table(df)[, "Bus"]`?

Comment: I edited the question with the precise answer you need. by changing the `dt$varnames` you can finely control the variables you need.

Comment: @AnnieTan I did a mistake copying the edited code. Now it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `table`.

We recreate your data.frame. Note that it's better to provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610)

```
df <- read.table(text="
Gender    Transportation.used
Male      Bus
Male      Car
Female    Car
Male      Car
Male      Motorcycle
Female    Bus", header=T)
```

Then you can use table:

```
table(df$Transportation.used, df$Gender) # here we type `df` twice
with(df, table(Transportation.used, Gender)) # `with` avoids that
```

In this special case where you have only two columns, `table(df)` also works and produces the desired output (transposed though).

If you really wants `Male` as the first column of your `table`, you can change the order of levels from the factor `Gender` (arranged alphabetically by default)

```
levels(df$Gender) # Female comes (alphabetically) before Male
df$Gender <- factor(df$Gender, levels=rev(levels(df$Gender))) # we rearrange Gender levels order
```

Now `with(df, table(Transportation.used, Gender))` is your exact desired output.

```
Gender
Transportation.used Male Female
Bus           1      1
Car           2      1
Motorcycle    1      0
```

The most basic graph (but see `?barplot`) you can get from this is:

```
tab <- with(df, table(Transportation.used, Gender))
barplot(tab)
```

---

(edit)

Then, if you want a table with a single trasnport mode, you can:

```
with(df, table(Transportation.used, Gender))["Bus",, drop=FALSE ]
                    Gender
Transportation.used Female Male
                Bus      1    1
```

Comment: I'm sorry I already fixed my question. What I mean is to calculate the frequency for gender based on **only one selected transport** in a table. I was able to find the frequency table for all the transports but not the selected one.

Comment: completed the answer